# My Update Stored Procedure not working some times and not showing error SQL Server 2008 R2 queries attached?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to update my project that is already ex sis in table. Stored procedure is working fine in some projects but not updating in some project even it is not giving any error I can't find out error I am pasting my queries down there please check it out if there is any issue.

Table creation query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Des_InventoryN]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Target_Project_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Projects] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Bridge_Cost] [money] NULL,
    [Hway_Cost] [money] NULL,
    [Bridge_Comp] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Hway_Comp] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Proj_WCB] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Proj_Owner] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Ind_Exp] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Sub] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Sub_Prime_Factor] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [M1] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [M2] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [M3] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [M4] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [M5] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [M6] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [M7] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [M8] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [M9] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [M10] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E1] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E2] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E3] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E4] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E5] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E6] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E7] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E8] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E9] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E10] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E11] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E12] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E13] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E14] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E15] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E16] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E17] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E18] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E19] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E20] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E21] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E22] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E23] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E24] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E25] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [E26] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [O1] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [O2] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [O3] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [O4] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [O5] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [O6] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [O7] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [O8] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [O9] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [O10] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [O11] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [O12] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [O13] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [O14] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [upsize_ts] [timestamp] NULL,
    [Creation] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Dnumber] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [EIS_Chap_IV] [bit] NULL,
    [EA_Chap_IV] [bit] NULL,
    [Proj_Flag] [bit] NULL,
    [Proj_Type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Cus_ID] [int] NULL,
    [SubPer] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Des_InventoryN] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Stored procedure for table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateProject] 
      @Target_Project_ID int,
      @Projects varchar(50),
      @Bridge_Cost money,
      @Hway_Cost money,
      @Bridge_Comp nvarchar(50),
      @Hway_Comp nvarchar(50),
      @ProjectType nvarchar(50),
      @Proj_Owner nvarchar(50),
      @Proj_WCB nvarchar(50),
      @Ind_Exp bit,
      @Sub bit,
      @M1 bit,
      @M2 bit,
      @M3 bit,
      @M4 bit,
      @M5 bit,
      @M6 bit,
      @M7 bit,
      @M8 bit,
      @M9 bit,
      @M10 bit,
      @E1 bit,
      @E2 bit,
      @E3 bit,
      @E4 bit,
      @E5 bit,
      @E6 bit,
      @E7 bit,
      @E8 bit,
      @E9 bit,
      @E10 bit,
      @E11 bit,
      @E12 bit,
      @E13 bit,
      @E14 bit,
      @E15 bit,
      @E16 bit,
      @E17 bit,
      @E18 bit,
      @E19 bit,
      @E20 bit,
      @E21 bit,
      @E22 bit,
      @E23 bit,
      @E24 bit,
      @E25 bit,
      @E26 bit,
      @O1 bit,
      @O2 bit,
      @O3 bit,
      @O4 bit,
      @O5 bit,
      @O6 bit,
      @O7 bit,
      @O8 bit,
      @O9 bit,
      @O10 bit,
      @O11 bit,
      @O12 bit,
      @O13 bit,
      @O14 bit,
      @Creation datetime,
      @Dnumber nvarchar(30),
      @SubPer nvarchar(30),
      @Sub_Prime_Factor nvarchar(30)      
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [InspectionDesign].[dbo].[Des_InventoryN] 
    SET
       [Projects] = @Projects
      ,[Bridge_Cost] = @Bridge_Cost
      ,[Hway_Cost] = @Hway_Cost
      ,[Bridge_Comp] = @Bridge_Comp 
      ,[Hway_Comp] = @Hway_Comp
      ,[Proj_WCB] = @Proj_WCB
      ,[Proj_Owner] = @Proj_Owner
      ,[Ind_Exp] = @Ind_Exp
      ,[Sub] = @Sub
      ,[M1] = @M1
      ,[M2] = @M2
      ,[M3] = @M3
      ,[M4] = @M4
      ,[M5] = @M5
      ,[M6] = @M6
      ,[M7] = @M7
      ,[M8] = @M8
      ,[M9] = @M9
      ,[M10] = @M10
      ,[E1] = @E1
      ,[E2] = @E2
      ,[E3] = @E3
      ,[E4] = @E4
      ,[E5] = @E5
      ,[E6] = @E6
      ,[E7] = @E7
      ,[E8] = @E8
      ,[E9] = @E9
      ,[E10] = @E10
      ,[E11] = @E11
      ,[E12] = @E12
      ,[E13] = @E13
      ,[E14] = @E14
      ,[E15] = @E15
      ,[E16] = @E16
      ,[E17] = @E17
      ,[E18] = @E18
      ,[E19] = @E19
      ,[E20] = @E20
      ,[E21] = @E21
      ,[E22] = @E22
      ,[E23] = @E23
      ,[E24] = @E24
      ,[E25] = @E25
      ,[E26] = @E26
      ,[O1] = @O1
      ,[O2] = @O2
      ,[O3] = @O3
      ,[O4] = @O4
      ,[O5] = @O5
      ,[O6] = @O6
      ,[O7] = @O7
      ,[O8] = @O8
      ,[O9] = @O9
      ,[O10] = @O10
      ,[O11] = @O11
      ,[O12] = @O12
      ,[O13] = @O13
      ,[O14] = @O14,
      [UpdateTime] = @Creation,
      [Dnumber] = @Dnumber,
      [Proj_Type] = @ProjectType,
      [SubPer] = @SubPer,
      [Sub_Prime_Factor] = @Sub_Prime_Factor
   WHERE 
      [ID] = @Target_Project_ID AND [Projects] = @Projects;
END
```

Query for passing parameters in stored procedure that is running fine but not updating project even not giving any error and displaying 1 row effected

I am just updating M1 value from 0 to 1 in this query while the rest of data is same so you have to insert data in table before updating same as mentioned in this query just M1 value 1 to 0

```
USE [InspectionDesign]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[UpdateProject]
        @Target_Project_ID = 63,
        @Projects = N'E. Third St 52nd St/LIRR & 19th St/NYCT Design & CSS',
        @Bridge_Cost = 5101000.0,
        @Hway_Cost = 953000.0,
        @Bridge_Comp = N'2',
        @Hway_Comp = N'1',
        @ProjectType = N'1',
        @Proj_Owner = N'4',
        @Proj_WCB = N'3',
        @Ind_Exp = false,
        @Sub = false,
        @M1 = 1,
        @M2 = 0,
        @M3 = 1,
        @M4 = 1,
        @M5 = 1,
        @M6 = 1,
        @M7 = 1,
        @M8 = 1,
        @M9 = 1,
        @M10 = 1,
        @E1 = 0,
        @E2 = 0,
        @E3 = 0,
        @E4 = 0,
        @E5 = 0,
        @E6 = 0,
        @E7 = 0,
        @E8 = 0,
        @E9 = 0,
        @E10 = 0,
        @E11 = 0,
        @E12 = 0,
        @E13 = 0,
        @E14 = 0,
        @E15 = 0,
        @E16 = 0,
        @E17 = 0,
        @E18 = 0,
        @E19 = 0,
        @E20 = 0,
        @E21 = 0,
        @E22 = 0,
        @E23 = 0,
        @E24 = 0,
        @E25 = 0,
        @E26 = 0,
        @O1 = 0,
        @O2 = 0,
        @O3 = 0,
        @O4 = 0,
        @O5 = 0,
        @O6 = 0,
        @O7 = 0,
        @O8 = 0,
        @O9 = 1,
        @O10 = 0,
        @O11 = 0,
        @O12 = 1,
        @O13 = 0,
        @O14 = 0,
        @Creation = N'4/1/2014 9:46:02 AM',
        @Dnumber = N'D031095',
        @SubPer = NULL,
        @Sub_Prime_Factor = N'1'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Hopes for your suggestion thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your Stored Procedure there is a where condition

```
where [ID] =@Target_Project_ID and [Projects]=@Projects;
```

you may update this as

```
where [Target_Project_ID] =@Target_Project_ID and [Projects]=@Projects;
```